# Facebook Review Submission Form and extended permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today I have created my new app in facebook developer portal. My application is an Android game and need to access friend list and publish permission.

The Submission form asks for the game apk to be uploaded with some pictures explaining why I need this permissions and the flow in the game. My question is, how am I supposed to send this if I haven't fully integrated facebook in my game? I expected to be able to finish my game in a sandbox or something and then when everything is ok I would send my game to facebook for reviewing it and accept/reject the permissions.

Please help with this issues because I'm stuck. I need to integrate facebook with this permissions but don't really know how to send all the information requested without even fully integrated facebook in my game.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always ask any person that have a role on the app for any permission. You don't have to get reviewed for that.

When you want to ask people that don't have a role on the app it is first then you need to get reviewed.

Comment: So, what I should be doing is add my testers, etc... and assign them a role and they will be able to use the app without being aproved. Well this is nice. Gonna check it! Thanks.

Comment: Yes add them as testers on your app. That is why we have the role tester :)